# Getting error while using Jquery Slider?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

While using the jquery slider in my aspx page with master page attached getting an error like

```
 The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.
```

And my code is

```
<div class="demo">
    <input type="text" class="sliderValue"  />
        <p>
        </p>
        <div id="slider"></div>
    </div>
```

and

```
<script language="javascript">
        $("#slider").slider({
            range: "min",
            value: 1,
            step: 10,
            min: 0,
            max: 1000,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("input").val(ui.value);
            }
        });


        $("input.sliderValue").change(function (event) {
            var value1 = parseFloat($("input").val());
            var highVal = value1 * 2;
            $("#slider").slider("option", { "max": highVal, "value": value1 });
        });
    </script>
```

Any suggestion??

EDIT:
But this piece of code is working fine in another aspx page.May i know the reason behind this

```
  <div>
  <input type="text" class="sliderValue" data-index="0" value="10" runat="server" />
  <input type="text" class="sliderValue" data-index="1" value="90" runat="server" />
  </div>
  <br />
  <div id="slider">
  </div>
```

and

```
<script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#slider").slider({
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                step: 1,
                range: true,
                values: [10, 90],
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < ui.values.length; ++i) {
                        $("input.sliderValue[data-index=" + i + "]").val(ui.values[i]);
                    }
                }
            });

            $("input.sliderValue").change(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                $("#slider").slider("values", $this.data("index"), $this.val());
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: you mentioned range: "min" wrong. It is should be a boolean value. You should specify true/false. Also check your value attribute mentioned correctly.

Comment: This looks like a server error, and may have nothing to do with jquery.  I would suggest putting the page in question online, and share the link.  I'm guessing the error has to do with a code-behind or something else that you haven't included in the snippets above.

Comment: the problem seems to be with the view state of the page either it is exceeding from its max length or may be some thing else, can you try setting the view state of page to false just o ensure whether this is the cause or not

Comment: take a look at this link it might help
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sv-SE/netfxbcl/thread/25f2886c-b560-434e-8dab-44a8adf4d34a

Answer (score 0):

try wrap your code in `$(document).ready(function(){});`

```
<script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#slider").slider({
            range: "min",
            value: 1,
            step: 10,
            min: 0,
            max: 1000,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("input").val(ui.value);
            }
        });


        $("input.sliderValue").change(function (event) {
            var value1 = parseFloat($("input").val());
            var highVal = value1 * 2;
            $("#slider").slider("option", { "max": highVal, "value": value1 });
        });

});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this, I hope this will help you

> 1. Add a "Debug=true" directive at the top of the file that generated the error. Example:

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>
```

> or:
>
> 2) Add the following section to the configuration file of your
>   application:

```
<configuration>    <system.web>
     <compilation debug="true"/>    </system.web> </configuration>
```

I have use your code and did not get any error like you told.

[image]

Comment: use my code and try in ur machine and tel whether its working or not